# How to reduce CPU usage

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,
Is normal to have a CPU usage of 85% when I am simulating the "empty.world" file?
And, if it is normal how can I reduce it?

I tried with the "update_rate" param but nothing changed

I have a:
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q8300  @ 2.50GHz
ATi Radeon HD 4350

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1376/how-to-reduce-cpu-usage/) by [AzCafre](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/213/azcafre/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-02-15**:
It's not exactly an answer to your problem, but I can tell you that it's processor dependent. Using the same amount of RAM and same video card, my CPU usage dropped hugely when switching from a Xeon quad core to a CORE i5.  Everything became a lot smoother too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I unistalled the proprietary fglrx driver for ATI Radeon and now I have a CPU usage of 5-10%

---

Originally posted by [AzCafre](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/213/azcafre/) with karma: 46 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

it's possible your computer does not have [high resolution timer](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Timer_Systems#.2Fproc.2Ftimer_list), in which case gazebo defaults to busy loop unless the sleep time requested is feasible.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1